# Will Microsoft abandon office add-ins?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-js, office-addins

I am already trying to develop Office-Addins for more than a year time (side projects needed for work but not a core business). Sadly, I am still feeling like an absolute noob. I tried to research all courses, documentations and SO questions about the matter but it looks like I just cannot advance. I am thinking that Microsoft will abandon Microsoft Add-ins. I tried to contact Microsoft and the developer program always points me to stack overflow So I did not know how to reach out. But I got the impression that the support for Add-ins is really weak and well because of the following reasons:

1. The Yeoman scaffolding for TypeScript React is really outdated and does not support Functional components but is required if you want to use Fluent UI React framework.
2. In my version of Windows 10, 2004, it is still not possible to see the developer tools but you stil need the beta Dev Edge DevTools, which remain in beta.
3. Decent debugging of Excel Add-ins with TypeScript React in VS code with breakpoints is impossible to get working (also when using [office debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msoffice.microsoft-office-add-in-debugger) because it crashes excel so dramatically that a forced shutdown of excel is needed.
4. every time something goes wrong with your TypeScript code, the Edge Dev tools tell you that the office.initialize is not properly loaded. So the user is completely on his own.
5. SPFx is promoted everywhere and on Pluralsight they say that an Add-in runs in an iFrame and that is limited.

I have multiple questions:

1. How to transform the Class component from the Yeoman generator to a fully functional component?
   if you go to the App.tsx file you will see this code:

   ```
   export default  class App extends React.Component<AppProps,   

   constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);
   }
   ```

But when I remove context, it does not work anymore. What is this context? Is this the Excel API?

2. How to get EdgeWebview2 to work? I have seen demo's but I cannot find the settings to change it?
3. Is it possible to have breakpoints with EdgeWebview2?
4. Does EdgeWebview2 give better feedback about what is wrong with your code?
5. Does a Excel Addin work together with SPFx?

many thanks for your explanation.

Comment: We're not a discussion forum and this isn't a code question. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the question and feedback. There's a few parts to your questions so I'm hoping I can help, as I work on the Excel extensibility platform.

a) If you're looking to build an add-in for Excel and work on cross platform, we would recommend you start with building web add-ins and use the resources here: https://aka.ms/office-add-ins.

b) In terms of "will we abandon office add-ins"?  No, we are continuing to invest in our Javascript add-ins. To learn about the latest on the Excel side, you can see our Ignite video here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IZjQQ9Kr2o), or attend our community calls: https://aka.ms/officeaddinscommunitycall  (which happen second wednesday of every month at 08:00 PST).

b) In terms of getting started,

- If you were getting started, checkout the quick start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react
- it sounds like you have tried some of our tools (Yeoman) but are hitting issues. For these, we have an active github channel. I'd suggest logging an issue there: https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues.  Can you log an issue on some of the challenges you are hitting and we can investigate (may be likely after the holidays)?

c) For your questions on Edge, the EdgeWebview2 runtime is currently rolling out to the monthly channel builds. You can find more information here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/office-add-ins-community-call-november-11-2020/, and we'll definitely post news about it once it does become available. Until then, you do have to use the beta channel for Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: we always saw promise from MS, and nothing done!

Comment: So... will you EVER fix office.js destroying EVERY SPA framework and its routing strategies?